# Is it possible to use bootstrap example pages for commercial sites

Tags: bootstrap-4

My question is quite simple:
 Can I use bootstrap example pages just like Cover or Pricing for commercial sites? And if so do I need to put their "Cover template for Bootstrap, by @mdo." disclaimer in my website footer?

I know that it can be a dumb question but I did not find anything about it in bootstrap's official site and I wan't to know if I can work with their example pages for commercial purposes to avoid legal issues before posting my project.

Comment: Yes you can, but it won't look professional

Comment: Hi man thanks for your help, this question was annoying me since I started my project. The only question left is if I need to put their "Cover template by..." in my footer... By the way your comment helped a lot, thanks man :D